# Where's selinux source code?

Tags: selinux, source

I'm trying to find url to selinux source code (both kernel and userland) but i can't find anything, only outdated urls... Could someone help? Also, I installed from packages in debian, so i guess i can't check it directly on my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SELinux kernel part is integrated into the vanilla kernel from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/). Just take a look into the directory ./security/selinux of your kernel source code.

The userland part of SELinux can be obtained [here](http://userspace.selinuxproject.org/).

Comment: maybe i'm dumb but i have trouble with browsing through kernel.org, could you give me link to selinux in for example newest kernel?

Comment: See e. g. http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=security/selinux

Answer (score 2):

SELinux kernel code is included in the mainline Linux 2.6 kernel, available from The Linux Kernel Archives.

http://www.kernel.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get source <whatever package SElinux is in>
```

Will get you the current source for the version of SElinux you're using.